# Flex order and tabindex

Tags: css

I'm using a third party plugin to show a form for adding and saving the Birthday.
It shows the input fields vertically ordered as:

Day
Year
Month

I used flex and order attribute to reorder the input fields as follow:

Day
Month
Year

But now if I tab through the inputs, the focus goes from Day to Year.

I would be able to fix it by using the tabindex inside the HTML markup, but I don't have access to the HTML.

Is there any other way to change the tabindex to: Day -> Month -> Year?

Comment: There is no other way to change the tab index in CSS other than javascript. Is JS an option?

Comment: Yes, JS would be an option.But don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way to change the tabindex to: Day -> Month -> Year?

No. When using <kbd>tab</kbd> the focus follows the order of elements in the HTML, unless `tabindex` attributes are present.

Changing the focus order is really not within the scope of CSS as a stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. As a javascript solution you could reassign the tabindex to the order value.

Here is part of the code I used to solve it :

```
/**
 * for ex. : ELEMENT_TO_SET = 'input,textarea'
 *           ELEMENT_WITH_ORDER_VALUE = document.getElementById('elementId')
 *
 * this will set all inputs and textareas that are containing in my element who has an order value
 */
$(ELEMENT_TO_SET).each(function(){
    $(this).attr("tabIndex", getComputedStyle(ELEMENT_WITH_ORDER_VALUE,null).order);
});
```